# Prove in natural deduction

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

“Ziggy is a lion who is not a carnivore. Therefore not all lions are carnivores.”

I translated it as:

$L(z) \land \lnot C(z)\vdash \lnot\forall x~[ L(x) \to C(x)]$

However, I have no idea how to prove it with natural deduction. Maybe someone could give me hints?

Comment: This is the 8th post: why not try to use the correct way to format symbols ?

Comment: z: ziggy.  L(z):= "ziggy is a lion".  $\lnot C(z):$= "ziggy is not carnivore.".  $L(z) \land \lnot C(z)$.  Existential generalization:  $$\exists(x)((L(x) \land \lnot C(x)) \equiv \exists(x)(\lnot(\lnot L(x) \lor C(x)) \equiv \exists x (\lnot (L(x) \to C(x))) \equiv \lnot \forall x (L(x \to C(x))$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\neg \forall x = \exists x \neg$.

Comment: Does it mean that conclusion is : ∃x[ L(x) ^ ¬C(x) ] ?

Comment: That means that the first step is to derive that from the premise using *a rule* from your proof system.